# Split a text file in C and give it a name

Tags: c, file, text, printing, split

i created a code to split text files when it finds the word "NEW DAY" and then save the file with a specific name.

First, i used File_Part1, File_Part2 and so on... However, i want to use the first 15 characters of the second line of the file i am reading as the name of the file saved.

For example, the second line is written: **TAM 2000-03-07T14:53...** i want to use only **TAM 2000-03-07**

The problem is that the function sprintf worked well for "%d", "%c" but is not working for "%s" and i don't have an idea why.

I tried to print the variable just before to see what the sprintf should be receiving and it is receiving just what i want...

Here is the code:

```
int TAM_BUFFER = 75; 
int filecounter=1, linecounter=1;

char fileoutputname[16];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char buffer[TAM_BUFFER];
char buffer2[15];


FILE *arquivo = fopen("Entrada.txt", "r");
FILE *saida;

sprintf(fileoutputname, "file_part%d.txt", filecounter);
saida = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");

if(arquivo != NULL){

    while(fgets(buffer, TAM_BUFFER, arquivo)){

        if(linecounter==2){
        strncpy(buffer2,buffer,14);
    }

    if (strncmp(buffer,"NEWDAY",strlen("NEWDAY")) == 0){
        fclose(saida);
        linecounter = 1;
        filecounter++;
        printf("%s", buffer2);
        sprintf(fileoutputname,"%s", buffer2);
        saida = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");
        if (!saida)
            return 1;       
    }

    fprintf(saida,"%s\n", buffer);
    linecounter++;

    }

} 

fclose(saida);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Add a `perror();` when `saida` is `NULL`. This could show an intersting error message.

Comment: You should also `fclose(arquivo)` at the end of your `main()`. (That won't solve your problem but you should always close files).

Comment: Hello @jdarthenay, thanks for the advice, i really forgot to close(arquivo). About the perror(), well, it said "No error". so i think it is ok.

Comment: The `printf("%s", buffer2);` is for debugging? Could you replace it with `printf("strlen(%s)=%d\n", buffer2, (int) strlen(buffer2));`?

Comment: Sorry @jdarthenay i haven't seen your comment.

The result was strlen< tam 2000-03-08>=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source is longer than the number of characters you copy, the [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) function will not add the string terminator, so `buffer2` might not contain the string terminator and when you treat it as a terminated string you will have *undefined behavior*.

The solution is very simple: Add the terminator manually.

Like

```
strncpy(buffer2,buffer,sizeof buffer2 - 1);
buffer2[sizeof buffer2 - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Hello Joachim, it can be possible, however i don't know why but it is not recognizing the character i am typing on the keyboard.

I mean, it did not worked, so i tried to add "N" at the buffer2[10] and it was not add, instead, was added a space "   " between the numbers where the "N" should be.

I guess it also occurs when i add '\0'...

Comment: If i use 

  sprintf(fileoutputname, "%c.txt", *buffer2);

it will save with the first letter of the second line, i mean, the letter "T"

But if i change for 

  sprintf(fileoutputname, "%s.txt", *buffer2);

it just crash the application...

Comment: I understand, i don't know why it works for %C, but doesn't matter. The thing is that if buffer2 is a string that can be printed with "%s" why it can not be used to name the file by:   

printf("%s", buffer2);
sprintf(fileoutputname, "%s.txt", buffer2);

Comment: @user3054811 When you dereference a pointer you get the value it points at. In your example doing `*buffer2` is the same as `buffer2[0]`. It's a single *character*. The `"%c"` format expects a single character. The `"%s"` format expects a *pointer* to a string of characters, terminated by a zero (not the character `'0'` but an actual zero, e.g. `0` or `'\0'`).

Comment: Alright Joachim, thank you for your help. Now i understood, really thank you.